# Border and interior of a topological subspace

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,\tau)$ a topological space, $Y\subset X$ and a sub-topological space $(Y, \tau_{Y})$

In class we proved that if $A\subset Y$ and the topological space $(Y, \tau_{Y})$ so if we denote $A^{-Y}$ the closure of $A$ in $(Y, \tau_{Y})$ and $A^-$ the closure of A, so $A^{-Y}=A^{-}\cap Y$.

But now I would like to know how the border and the interior of $A$ behaves with respect to $(Y, \tau_{Y})$

Answer (score 0):

Given a topological space S, the set S is clopen (open and closed).
Because of this the interior of S is S and it's boundary or border is empty.
The same is true of subspaces because they are topological spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Interior and 'border' (which is usually called boundary) also behave the same way. For example the boundary of $A$ in $Y$ is the intersection with $Y$ of the boundary of $A$ in $X$.